# The subring criterion

Tags: ring-theory

As we know that the subring criterion states that a subset $H$ of ring $R$ is a subring if and only if :

(1) $H$ is non-void , and

(2) for all $x,y \in H$,$x-y \in H$.

(3) product $xy \in H$ .

The thing I can't understand is why we need to ensure that product $xy \in H$?Even if we don't ensure that what will happen for $H$ to be a subring.I don't find it intutive because $R$ is not a group under multiplication. Please help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want $H$ to also be a ring, so our multiplication can't let us get "outside" it. For example, let $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and $H$ be all elements of the form $ax + b$ (for $a, b \in \mathbb{Z})$. This is a perfectly valid sub *group* of $R$, but it's not a ring: $x \in H$, but $x \cdot x$ is not.

If you know what monoids are, another way to think of the subring criterion is this: $(H, +)$ must be a subgroup of $(R, +)$, and $(H, \cdot)$ must be a submonoid of $(R, \cdot)$. (If you don't require your rings to have an identity, replace "monoid" with "semigroup").

Comment: Thanks for the nice example.Another thing I want to understand is this: We call $H$ to be a subring if it is closed under + and $\times $ and also contains multiplicative identity of $R$.My doubt is why is multiplicative identity of  $R$ required to be in $H$ ,if $R$ has it...

Comment: There's not really an answer for that. Some people require a ring to have a multiplicative identity, and some do. It's unfortunate that we don't have separate names for the two concepts. So, depending on which definition you use, $H$ may or may not need a multiplicative identity. If this is for a course, ask your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

A ring needs to have two laws $+$ and $\times$. The condition $(3)$ allow us the second law for $H$.

Comment: What does it has to do with the closure under multiplication.Please explain..

Comment: When $H$ is closed under $\times$, this allow us to define a law in $H$, as :$ H\times H \to H, (x,y) \mapsto x \times y.$

Comment: Ah Now I understood!! Thanks...